# Why does this function compile if the return type annotation is a reference to a string but it's returning a string literal?

Tags: pointers, rust, reference

The type annotation is `&str`, which is a pointer to a string, right? but I'm returning a string, either `foo` or `bar`, or `baz`. Why does this code work

```
pub fn foo_if_fizz(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    if fizzish == "fizz" {
        "foo"
    } else if fizzish == "fuzz" {
        "bar"
    } else {
        "baz"
    }
}
```

Comment: `'static` lives at least as long as any other lifetime.

Comment: Because string literals have type `&'static str`.

Comment: `"baz".to_string` is a string `"baz"` is a string literal

Answer (score 0):

`&str` is the [type of string literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html).

The caller receives a shared, immutable reference. They are not the owner, and hence cannot modify the contents or drop the data. Calling this function twice with the same arguments returns references to the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

> The type annotation is `&str`, which is a pointer to a string, right?

This depends on how you define "string."

If you mean "a pointer into a `String`" then the answer is... they can be that, but they can also point at other things.  So you *cannot* say "I have a `&str`, therefore it definitely came from a `String`."

A `&str`, called a "string slice" in Rust, is a *fat pointer* which contains two pieces of information: a pointer to a byte, and a length in bytes.  Rust requires that the entire byte sequence referenced (starting at the pointed-to byte and spanning the length) is a valid UTF-8 sequence on its own.

That's it, there's nothing magical about it.

Here's a list of some of the places you can obtain a `&str` (there are still others):

- `String` will auto-deref into a `&str`.  You can also explicitly say `some_string.as_str()`.
- From a `&str` you can obtain another `&str` that references a subsection.
- You can view a `&[u8]` (slice of bytes) as a `&str` using [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).  This does not copy any data, it only validates that the byte slice is a valid UTF-8 sequence and returns a string slice over the same data.
- String literals (`"foo"`) have type `&str` with a `'static` lifetime, meaning they are valid for the entire duration of the program.  **That's why your sample code works.**